# How to catch the event when user taps on push notification in angularjs

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, push

I am try to send the push notifications from one device to another device.My requirement is once notification has sent to device when user taps on it app browser should get open with three buttons, need to capture the button event which user has clicked in angularjs.

Now sending  push notifications are done. I have used ionic.io plugins to send notifications.

Could anybody help me to catch the event when user taps on notifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the onNotification callback gets executed whenever a notification is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. How to make custom notification as of now I am getting alert

Comment: See the documentation, --> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md